# AFNetworking api call after geofence or beacon event

Tags: ios, iphone, background, afnetworking-2, geofencing

I'm trying to make an API call after getting "didEnterRegion" call. When the app is on front, it works great. But if the app is deactivated or even in background, the call is never made. I tried to debug it but once "reportLocationEventToServerWithType" is called the debugger "dies" and the call is never made.  I don't think it matters, but i'm using Estimote sdk for the beacon monitoring. 
Here are the code snippets:

```
   - (void)beaconManager:(id)manager didEnterRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{


UIApplication *app                = [UIApplication sharedApplication];



NSNumber * mallID = [self.dictBeaconsPerMall objectForKey:region.identifier];
Mall * mall = [Mall getMallWithID:mallID];

[ApplicationManager sharedInstance].locationManager.beaconRecognizedMall=mall;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:nLocationMallUpdated object:nil];
UILocalNotification * not = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    not.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DID Enter beacon region at: %@",mall.strTitle];
    not.alertAction = @"alertAction";
    not.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [app presentLocalNotificationNow:not];


[[ApplicationManager sharedInstance].crashAndReportsManager reportLocationEventToServerWithType:@"beacon" andSubParam:region.identifier extraInfo:@{@"paramKey":@"key"}];
}


-(void)reportLocationEventToServerWithType: (NSString*)type andSubParam:(NSString*) strID extraInfo: (NSDictionary*)extraInfo{

    NSString* udid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [params setObject:type forKey:@"type"];
    [params setObject:strID forKey:@"subParam"];
    [params setObject:udid forKey:@"udid"];

    if(extraInfo)
        [params addEntriesFromDictionary:extraInfo];
    UserLogRequest * req = [[UserLogRequest alloc]initWithCallerObject:self andParams:params];
    req.showHud=NO;
    req.showMessage=NO;
    [[ApplicationManager sharedInstance].requestManager sendRequestForRequest:req];
```

}

The request initialization and the request manager "sendRequestForRequest" are working fine in million other situations so their implementation is irrelevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Background execution is little bit different in ios. you can't execute in background without some settings from capabilities under project target. you should enable background execution from it for specific requirement like location, audio etc. and then you should implement code accordingly.

You have limited options to execute in background like audioplaying, location updating, finite length task, voice over ip etc.

refer this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for more detail on background execution and you can google background execution you will got some good results.

So, reason of not working your task in background is this that you have not properly configured it.

hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that also, but nothing. Mentioned the location background modes in plist and tried to do it with background task. Still no success...

Comment: you can't call api from background.